# How to use libpcap to parse pcap file.

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap

I want to parse only RTP packets from a `.pcap` file generated from WireShark using `libpcap` library.
I have seen number of example that works on device to get the packets using `libpcap` but i am not able to find any example that can extract specific packets from the `.pcap` file.

anyone knows link to such examples or anyone having sample code for doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libpcap uses the functions **pcap_compile** and **pcap_setfilter** (described [here](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section3.html) with example code) to filter packets before starting the capture loop. The filter syntax is described in the [man page for TCPDump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)

Filtering RTP packets presents a further challenge as they are not sent over a standard port and there is no other convenient method for detecting the protocol. The ports used for RTP are negotiated by the the control channel protocol (such as SIP) preceding the RTP setup. [This example](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=aaa.pcap) contains a SIP message where the line **rport=5060** gives the UDP port used for RTP (see below).

Detection of RTP therefore requires inspecting the SIP protocol packets (or other signalling protocol to figure out the RTP ports to filter on.

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Call-ID: 29858147-465b0752@29858051-465b07b2
Contact: pel<sip:35104723@192.168.1.2:5060;line=7d36558f31367051>;q=0.500;expires=1200
CSeq: 6 REGISTER
From: <sip:35104723@sip.cybercity.dk>;tag=659abf
P-Associated-URI: <sip:35104723@sip.cybercity.dk>
To: <sip:35104723@sip.cybercity.dk>;tag=00-04087-1701bae7-76fb74995
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.2;received=80.230.219.70;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKnp6658824-465059f1192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am going to parse static .pcap file so how do i start with, is there any direct filter option to `pcap_compile` function or do i need to use BPF for this. if BPF then how do i specify protocol in it?

Comment: you would pass a BPF filter such as 'UDP port 5060' to filter for SIP traffic. You can try this out using tcpdump -r to read from your static capture file